# Run-time error 91 on code of exporting charts to PowerPoint

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I am trying to export charts from Excel to PowerPoint, but when executed it shows the error 91 saying "Object variable or With block variable not set"

I already did research and did not find anything that could help me. Here is the code.

```
Sub ExportChartstoPowerPoint()
Dim PPApp As Object
Dim chr
Set PPApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
PPApp.Presentations.Add
PPApp.ActiveWindow.ViewType = ppViewSlide
For Each chr In Sheets("CPIT Overview").ChartObjects
    PPApp.ActivePresentation.Slides.Add PPApp.ActivePresentation.Slides.Count + 1, ppLayoutBlank
    PPApp.ActiveWindow.View.GotoSlide PPApp.ActivePresentation.Slides.Count
    chr.Select
    ActiveChart.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Size:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture
    PPApp.ActiveWindow.View.Paste
    PPApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Align msoAlignCenters, True
    PPApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Align msoAlignMiddles, True
Next chr
PPApp.Visible = True
End Sub
```

The error is in the line `ActiveChart.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Size:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture`

Comment: Using early binding?  You define `PPApp` as an `object` indicating it could be late binding, but then use `ppViewSlide` which only Powerpoint would understand (unless you've defined it elsewhere) so early binding?

Comment: Does it still do it if you change `ActiveChart.CopyPicture....` to `chr.Chart.CopyPicture....`?  This reduced code didn't return any errors:  `Sub Test(): Dim chr As ChartObject: For Each chr In Sheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects: chr.Chart.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Size:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture: Next chr: End Sub`  **Edit:**  Pausing the code after a CopyPicture let me paste into Paint so it does work.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook it works! thank you! :)

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook hi again! I want to change my code so instead of creating a blank presentation it is done with an specific custom template, I found a code online for this by using a string variable and a with loop, but when I try it does not apply my template, could you help me with this?

Comment: Rather than use `PPApp.Presentations.Add` use `PPApp.Presentations.Open("path to template")`